# How to build a tightly consistent item assortment table with pagination, sort, filter and search?

Tags: sorting, pagination, architecture, microservices, data-consistency

I am building a item aggregator page. It is basically a webpage that shows a table with the items assortment of an e commerce sellers. This tables can contains thousand of rows. It should be paginated, sortable, filterable and have a search bar. Additionally all items can be edited (fields like state, item name, price, tags and so on). Many of those fields come from different micro services. Therefore there is a backend that takes care of the aggregating all data points listening to updates on each entity. However there is a standard network latency in the system from the moment a change is triggered in the frontend to the moment is stored in the db. This means that if the user sorts the table right after editing a field, the sorting might be inconsistent with the data. One solution to fix this would be to built a big monolith with all aggregate entities but it's problematic for many reasons. Do you have some suggestions more?